# Are goals counting Multiple Times per User Session?

Tags: google-analytics

I have created a goal in GA based on a virtual pageview:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/actionOne']);
```

Im almost sure that goal is counted each time user generates pageview (not unique), am I right?
If yes - how to make it unique, not each time trigerred by user.

Thanks

Comment: Actually this would count as 100 pageviews but one visit.

Comment: but in funnels/goals its been tracked as not unique, any advice?

Comment: I edited the question to ask what you obviously meant to ask. But goals are counted only once per user session, there is no way around it.

Comment: Actually its other way round, Im pretty sure that its triggered each time for one user, not once.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Eike, just see is this useful to you.https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables.

Answer (score 0):

Use [EventTracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) for this purpose. Events unlike counversions can be counted numerous times. To see related data, set up a goal based on this event, then created a specific segment that would include only those visits (or visitors - depending on your needs) that converted.